# PHPStorm laravel issues

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpstorm, user-permissions

I was having a bit of trouble getting PHPStorm to work with laravel/composer.

Upon opening PHPStorm, I created a new Composer Project: http://puu.sh/e4y1H/6fb97cf976.png

After which, I filled in necessary the details: http://puu.sh/e4y6Z/55bc60e7fc.png

After continuing, I run into the following error:

```
php /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/test/composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel 
/Users/mdobrenko/Sites/test/composer -n --no-progress
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.11)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.11)
    Loading from cache

Created project in /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/test/composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.8)
    Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.8)



  [ErrorException]                          
  touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied  

create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

The 'Sites' directory that I store my development projects in, which is where this project lives, has the following permissions set:

```
drwxrwxrwx   11 mdobrenko  staff   374 Jan  4 13:40 Sites
```

I noticed that most of my php artisan commands require the use of 'sudo'. Creating a new laravel project via the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

I have a feeling permissions may be the issue, but I am unsure of how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this [link](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12154) should help. Try clearing the composer cache, re-installing composer, Chown the Sites folder to the same user as the apache server uses

Comment: That did it for me; I simply had to chown the sites/laravel folder to the proper user. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as answer so that we can close the question down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12154) should help. Try clearing the composer cache, re-installing composer, Chown the Sites folder to the same user as the apache server uses

To clear the composer cache, open a terminal and cd into your project folder: `sudo composer clear-cache` (sudo may not be required here)

Changing permissions: `chown -R $(whoami): .` this sets the owner of all files and sudirectories to the current user. giving you permission to access the files.

Comment: the site is down. could you explain the steps necessary to solve the problem?